# É possível utilizar EcmaScript 6 sem Babel ou Webpack?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, ecmascript

Como nos velhos tempos, seria possível simplesmente incluir um arquivo EcmaScript 6 **no navegador** e usar suas funcionalidades sem a necessidade de "transpilar" estes códigos?

Answer (score 1):

Com exceção do Internet Explorer, a maioria dos navegadores suportam as sintaxes do ES6, ES2016, ES2017 e ES2018.

Sim, é possível escrever o código diretamente sem transpilador. É recomendável? Isso é subjetivo.

Sites como W3schools e MDN costumam documentar quais funcionalidades são suportadas por cada navegador, mas mesmo esses sites não possuem documentação completa, no fim do dia cabe a você jugar o que deve ser feito.

Por experiência (leia-se, subjetivo), acredito que `arrow function`, `async/await`, `for..of`, `spread operator`, `let/const` são relativamente seguros para se usar diretamente em navegadores. `import/export` por outro lado não é suportado por nenhum navegador.

Comment: Seja bem-vindo ao StackOverflow. Obrigado pela sua resposta, no entanto me gerou uma dúvida. Estava pesquisando e ví que é possível utilizar import e export incluindo a tag script da seguinte forma: ```<script src="main.js" type="module"></script>```. Isto ainda seria ES6?

Comment: Eles não são equivalentes. `import` e `export` são macros para importar módulos, utilizados principalmente no NodeJS, de forma similar ao `import` e `public` de outras linguagens de programação.

Comment: Encontrei neste site: https://jakearchibald.com/2017/es-modules-in-browsers/